# Infinitely many primes $p$ such that $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

After asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833075/infinitely-many-primes-p-such-that-fracp-12-is-a-product-of-two-primes) and receiving interesting comments, the following, seemingly easier, question arises:

> Are there infinitely many primes $p$ such that $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is a prime number?

**Examples** for $(p,\frac{p-1}{2})$: $(5,2),(7,3),(11,5),(23,11)$.

**Remark:** Unfortunately, I did not understand the claims in the comments of the above mentioned question, so perhaps my current question has a positive answer by those comments (please see my last comment there, in which I ask if Lemma 1 of https://academic.oup.com/qjmath/article-abstract/37/1/27/1515517?redirectedFrom=PDF answers my current question).

**Edit:** After reading the answer below, I guess that "seemingly easier" should be deleted.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A positive answer to this question would imply that there are infinitely many [Sophie Germain primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime), but this is not known.

Comment: Thank you very much! Please, what about my former question? What Lemma 1 (adjusted to my question) shows?